# Merge multiple audio files into one file

Tags: audio, merge, uwp, media, uwp-xaml

I want to **merge** two audio files and produce one final file. For example if `file1` has length of 5 minutes and `file2` has length of 4 minutes, I want the result to be a single 5 minutes file, because both  files will start from 0:00 seconds and will run together (i.e **overlapping.**)

Comment: Does it work for you to play 2 files simultaneously? It will have the same result as you described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the APIs in the [Windows.Media.Audio namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Audio) to create audio graphs for audio routing, mixing, and processing scenarios. For how to create audio graphs please reference [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/audio-graphs#starting-and-stopping-audio-graph-nodes).

An audio graph is a set of interconnected audio nodes. The two audio files you want to merge supply the "audio input nodes", and "audio output nodes" are the destination single file for audio processed by the graph.

The scenario 4 of  [AudioCreatio official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation) - Submix, just provide the feature you want. Provide two files it will output the mixed audio, but change the output node to [`AudioFileOutputNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Audio.AudioFileOutputNode) for saving to a new file since the sample create `AudioDeviceOutputNode` for playing.